# jquery not returning body.text

Tags: php, jquery

I have an ajax post sends a website address to php it retrieves it and then I want jquery to find certain elements within the site and retrieve the text in those elements. It works fine for a few elements like h1 h2 p a etc but not on all sites and I can't get body text and meta tags i.e. body.text returns nothing.  Is it my ajax post or php causing the problem here?

Here is my ajax post

```
var dataString = name;

            $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "senddom.php",
      data: {"dataString" : dataString },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
  $('body').append("<p> contents of title:" + $(response).find("Title").text()+ "</p>");          
  $('body').append("<p> contents of meta:" + $(response).find('Meta').text()+ "</p>");      
  $('body').append("<p> contents of all: " + $(response).find('body').text() + "</p>");

 $(response).find('p').each(function() {
  $('body').append("<p> contents of p: " + $(this).text() + "</p>");
});
```

and my php which I have only started learning

```
<?php 
    $site= $_POST['dataString'];             // get data
function curl_get($site){
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$site);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);   
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

function getdom($site){
    $html = curl_get($site);
    // Create a new DOM Document
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    @$xml->loadHTML($html);
   echo json_encode($html);  
}
echo getdom($site);
?>
```

Comment: can you add a sample structure for response?

Comment: do you mean what it outputs when I run it?

Comment: contents of title:

contents of meta:

contents of all:

contents of p: Hello,Welcome to Play.com.  . (Not youSign in?) | Create an account You've earned Save with SuperPoints

contents of p: Search Suggestions

contents of p: View Basket

contents of p: The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn - Part 2

Comment: it appears better than that with spacing etc but as you can see for the other tags ie meta it is just blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On jQuery doc, I found something interessing.
We can't use `.text()` method on script. So I'm pretty sure, you got script in your body, and so `.text()` doesn't work.
Use `.html()`, it should work.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: thank you i tried this before and when I do this it comes up undefined beside body